# How to select and display a live table with kotlin, room, mvvm?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

In my First fragment, I create the team name (corresponding to my team_table).

Then, I move on to the fragment for adding player names. I would like to display directly and only the list of players corresponding to the team. It seems to work when I want to update a player's name and come back to that player list. Otherwise, it shows me the list of all the players of all the teams. How can I do, please?

Here's my code:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val readAllDataTeam: LiveData<List<Team>>?
    val readAllDataUser: LiveData<List<User>>?
    val readAllDataEval: LiveData<List<Eval>>?
    val readAllDataUserWithEval: LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>?
    val readAllDataTeamWithUser: LiveData<List<TeamWithUser>>?

    private val repositoryTeam: UserRepository
    private val repositoryUser: UserRepository
    private val repositoryEval: UserRepository
    private val repositoryUserWithEval: UserRepository
    private val repositoryTeamWithUser: UserRepository

    init {
        val teamDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
        repositoryTeam = UserRepository(teamDao!!)
        readAllDataTeam = repositoryTeam.readAllDataTeam

        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
        repositoryUser = UserRepository(userDao!!)
        readAllDataUser = repositoryUser.readAllDataUser

        val evalDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
        repositoryEval = UserRepository(evalDao!!)
        readAllDataEval = repositoryEval.readAllDataEval

        val userEvalDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
        repositoryUserWithEval = UserRepository(userEvalDao!!)
        readAllDataUserWithEval= repositoryUserWithEval.readAllDataUserEval

        val teamUserDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
        repositoryTeamWithUser = UserRepository(teamUserDao!!)
        readAllDataTeamWithUser = repositoryTeamWithUser.readAllDataTeamWithUser
    }

    //Team

    fun addTeam(team: Team) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryTeam.addTeam(team)
        }
    }

    fun updateTeam(team: Team) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryTeam.updateTeam(team)
        }
    }

    fun deleteTeam(team: Team) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryTeam.deleteTeam(team)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllTeams() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryTeam.deleteAllTeams()
        }
    }


    //Eval

    fun addEval(eval: Eval) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryEval.addEval(eval)
        }
    }

    fun updateEval(eval: Eval) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryEval.updateEval(eval)
        }
    }

    fun deleteEval(eval: Eval) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryEval.deleteEval(eval)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllEvals() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryEval.deleteAllEvals()
        }
    }

    //User

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryUser.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun updateUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryUser.updateUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryUser.deleteUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllUsers() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repositoryUser.deleteAllUsers()
        }
    }

    fun searchDatabase(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<User>>? {
        return repositoryUser.searchDatabase(searchQuery)
    }
    fun searchDatabaseTeam(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<Team>>? {
        return repositoryUser.searchDatabaseTeam(searchQuery)
    }

    fun getTeam(searchTeam: String): LiveData<List<User>>? {
        return repositoryUser.getTeam(searchTeam)
    }
}
```

**class UserRepository:**

```
class UserRepository (private val userDao: UserDao) {
    val readAllDataUser: LiveData<List<User>>? = userDao.getUserData()

    val readAllDataEval: LiveData<List<Eval>>? = userDao.getEvalData()

    val readAllDataTeam: LiveData<List<Team>>? = userDao.getTeamData()

    val readAllDataUserEval: LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>? = userDao.getAllUserWithEval()

    val readAllDataTeamWithUser: LiveData<List<TeamWithUser>>? = userDao.getAllTeamWithUser()

    //User
    suspend fun addUser(user: User) {
        userDao.addUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun updateUser(user: User) {
        userDao.updateUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        userDao.deleteUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllUsers() {
        userDao.deleteAllUsers()
    }

    //Eval
    suspend fun addEval(eval: Eval) {
        userDao.addEval(eval)
    }

    suspend fun updateEval(eval: Eval) {
        userDao.updateEval(eval)
    }

    suspend fun deleteEval(eval: Eval) {
        userDao.deleteEval(eval)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllEvals() {
        userDao.deleteAllEvals()
    }

    //Eval
    suspend fun addTeam(team: Team) {
        userDao.addTeam(team)
    }

    suspend fun updateTeam(team: Team) {
        userDao.updateTeam(team)
    }

    suspend fun deleteTeam(team: Team) {
        userDao.deleteTeam(team)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllTeams() {
        userDao.deleteAllTeams()
    }

    fun searchDatabase(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<User>>? {
        return userDao.searchDatabase(searchQuery)
    }

    fun searchDatabaseTeam(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<Team>>? {
        return userDao.searchDatabaseTeam(searchQuery)
    }

    fun getTeam(searchTeam: String): LiveData<List<User>>? {
        return userDao.getTeam(searchTeam)
    }
```

**interface UserDao:**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getUserData(): LiveData<List<User>>?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun addUser(user: User)

    @Update
    fun insertEval(eval: Eval)

    @Update
    fun updateUser(user: User)

    @Delete
    fun deleteUser(user: User)

    @Query("DELETE FROM user_table")
    fun deleteAllUsers()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id=:id")
    fun getOneUser(id: Int): User

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table JOIN eval_table  on user_table.id = eval_table.idEval ")
    fun getAllUserWithEval(): LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE firstName LIKE :searchQuery OR lastName LIKE :searchQuery OR nbTeam LIKE :searchQuery OR nameTeam LIKE :searchQuery")
    fun searchDatabase(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<User>>?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM team_table WHERE  nameTeam LIKE :searchQuery")
    fun searchDatabaseTeam(searchQuery: String): LiveData<List<Team>>?

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE nameTeam LIKE :searchTeam")
    fun getTeam(searchTeam: String): LiveData<List<User>>?
```

**class ListFragment:**

```
class ListFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    //Pour accéder au fab
    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    private val args by navArgs<ListFragmentArgs>()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container,false)
        val view = binding.root
        //Recyclerview pour affichier le custom row et les données
        val adapter = ListAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        val searchTeam = args.currentTeam.nameTeam

        binding.tvNameTeam.text = searchTeam

        // UserViewModel pour afficher les données
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)


        mUserViewModel.getTeam(searchTeam)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            userT -> adapter.setData(userT)
        })
        /*
        mUserViewModel.getTeam(args.currentTeam.nameTeam)
            ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { userT ->
                adapter.setData(userT)
            })

         */

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        // Add menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu)
        val search = menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
        val searchView = search?.actionView as? SearchView
        searchView?.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        return
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_delete){
            deleteAllUsers()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun deleteAllUsers() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes"){ _, _ ->
            mUserViewModel.deleteAllUsers()
            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "Suppression complète réussie",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        builder.setNegativeButton("No"){_, _ -> }
        builder.setTitle("Tout Supprimer?")
        builder.setMessage("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer l'ensemble des données?")
        builder.create().show()
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
        if(query != null){
            searchDatabase(query)
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun searchDatabase(query: String) {
        val searchQuery = "%$query%"

        val adapter = ListAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        mUserViewModel.searchDatabase(searchQuery)?.observe(this, { userT->
            userT.let {
                adapter.setData(it)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**class ListAdapter:**

```
class ListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var userTList = emptyList<User>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) { }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userTList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItemUT = userTList[position]

        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_txt).text = currentItemUT.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.firstName_txt).text = currentItemUT.firstName
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastName_txt).text = currentItemUT.lastName
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numeroTeam_txt).text = currentItemUT.nbTeam.toString()

        holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.rowLayout).setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToUpdateFragment(currentItemUT)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

        holder.itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_start_eval).setOnClickListener {
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToEvalFragment(currentItemUT)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userTList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Comment: _"It seems to work when I want to update a player's name and come back to that player list. Otherwise, it shows me the list of all the players of all the teams. "_ Does that mean different code is behaving differently, and if so what parts of the code you posted, or is it a matter of certain steps-to-reproduce?

Comment: When i change the code, it's the same. The first step is list group fragment to create a team name and the second step is the list fragment. I don't know why the result appear after